# execute a whois unix command using system()

Tags: php, unix, system, whois

Is there a way / is it possible to execute the unix whois query using php, possibly using system().?

I am trying

```
echo '<pre>';
$last_line = system('whois ryansmurphy.com', $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
```

but it doesnt work. what am i doing wrong?

Am seeing nothing, no errors, no output.

Comment: That should work, what's your question? Maybe it's not working because you're using backticks instead of quotes?

Comment: @sorry for poor explanation. See update

Comment: What doesn't work? What output/errors are you seeing? What are you trying to do?

Comment: check if `$last_line` is false. if it is, the command failed.

Comment: Do you get a result when you run `passthru('whois ryansmurphy.com');` ?

Comment: return value was commented out and i uncomment it and it returns 127? does anyone know what this means

Comment: 127 means command not found. recompose your code as `system('/path/to/dir/with/whois ryansmurphy.com', $retval);` Good luck.

Comment: Do not go to the shell to start a whois command from your PHP program. Use the specific libraries that you have in your language to do whois queries or just read RFC3912 on whois and open a TCP socket on port 43 to send your request terminated by CR + LF

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
exec($command, $output, $exit_code);
```

Where:

$command - your command ("whois ...")

$output - command output.

$exit_code - command exit code

[exec command PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: No, do not use `exec` from PHP to do a whois query.

Answer (score 0):

If the command is not returning anything, then it is most likely returning an error to standard error, which isn't being captured.  Try adding `2>&1` to send the errors to standard out.

`$last_line = system('whois ryansmurphy.com 2>&1', $retval);`

This is covered in the PHP Manual for [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#21427) and [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#100269)

Comment: No, do not use `system` from PHP to do a whois query.